# Painting with Android - invalidate() or postInvalidate()

Tags: android, paint

I've been getting back into the Android OS and decided to investigate canvas and painting.

I came across some code [here](http://androidbite.blogspot.com/2012/10/android-paint-example.html) that creates a simple paint application. But I am alittle confused about one thing. In the paint class it does this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    // Point holds two integer coordinates
    Point point = new Point();
    point.x = event.getX();
    point.y = event.getY();

    // Add the coordinates to the array list
    points.add(point);

    invalidate();

    Log.d(TAG, "point: " + point);
    return true;
}
```

According to the hover-message over `invalidate()`:

> This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call postInvalidate(). 
>   Invalidate the whole view. 
>   If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future. This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call postInvalidate().

So - shouldn't this be calling `postInvalidate()` instead of `invalidate()` because the Paint class isn't the UI - the main activity is? Just wanted to get an opinion on this.

P.S. I have tried both and `postInvalidate()` works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any callback to a touch event is on the UI thread. Your understanding is correct but you are wrong about the thread that is being used. If this was on a background thread you would use postInvalidate().

One thing to remember is that code you have in the Activity class doesn't necessarily run on the UI thread. When the documentation talks about running on the UI it means that the code must be executed on the UI thread. Any code in any class can be run on the UI thread using a few different methods. With this in mind it is possible to execute the same code on the UI thread as well as in a background thread. Check out the example below which would live inside an Activity.

UI Thread:

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            myFunction();
    });
```

Background Thread:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            myFunction();
    }).start();
```